# Can we use C++ for Web design/development/programming?

Tags: c++, web, scripting

Can we use C++ programming language to do web design/development/programming? If yes Where I can learn to do this? Do we use it as a scripting language or something else? Please write as more specific that you can. Thanks!

*"I don't want to use Visual-C++ or Asp.net"*

Comment: Yes, you can use C++ to program a server-side web application. Most HTTP servers support the FastCGI protocol, so if your application provides the appropriate interface, it can be used to generate web pages to be served by HTTP. That doesn't make it a scripting language though.

Comment: Sure you can... write an apache or nginx module.

Comment: Can you post your answer and don't comment. I need more details. @JosephMansfield

Comment: Can you post your answer and don't comment.  I need more details. @NG.

Comment: You can, but would you really want to..?

Comment: @NavidRashidian They posted comments, because these should be. Your question is too broad to write a halfway good answer for it.

Comment: CPPCMS is a good c++ web development framework. http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/main

Comment: Please post an answer @PeterR

Comment: I suggest you to look at [Go](http://golang.org) -- it has been created at Google out of frustration with C++ compilation speeds and other hassles, and it's now in wide use for web development (including Google's own services like `dl.google.com`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the server side programming you can. It's not that common from what I've told. It's mostly used in time critical situations. Where to learn depends on what framework you intend to use on your server back end. You could also of course make your own http server. All you do is sending text strings over a network.

On the client side it's more difficult. Web readers does most often only support sandboxes programs to run. C++ is not suitable for sandboxes environment and posses a major security risk. Just imagine if you open a website and it contains a c++ program with major memory leaks.

Answering to your scripting question. No you don't use C++ as a scripting language. Scripts are interpreted. If you want some kind of scripting language you better lookup one existing. If it's for performance reasons you want to use C++ it must be used natively.

Another thing that makes it unsuitable for clients is that's it's platform dependent.

If it's making your own server back end you were interested in, you should check out the http protocol (HyperText Transfer Protocol). Here's a link to begin with: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: Can you please explain about the frameworks?

Answer (score 2):

Web design involves writing HTML for structured content and CSS for its presentation.

Now, if you're talking about writing a web based application... Yes, you may use C++ to write the server side backend which would generate your pages. FastCGI is a standard that is supported quite widely and you may use it to access C++ code on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can write web stuff in c++. You must be more specific what exactly you want to do. Maybe c++ is not the right tool for the job.
But you can look at some existing frameworks. Maybe they do what you want.
Just to name two of them. [WT](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or [tntnet](http://www.tntnet.org/). There are definitly more.

Answer (score 1):

One of the option to use C++ in web programming is [nodejs](http://nodejs.org).
You can write [addons](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) in C++ for it.
For example you can write an addon that is using websockets and control your webpage dynamically.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily convoluted. Node is a JS oriented platform. Yes, add ons may be written indeed but do you really want to?

Comment: Why not? It is always a good idea to learn new things. Is JS combined with C++ a good option for you? You won't know if you don't try.

Comment: Alright, I concede. It's always a good thing to try things firsthand.

Answer (score 1):

See [c++ server side pages](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpollcppsp/). If you need to write a client side code, you can use [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki) to compile you c++ or c code to javascript.